# TimerTask stops executing all of a sudden

Tags: java, android, service, timertask

My application has a `T_Service`, that has a TimerTask class, `B_TimerTask` that bundles up data at a fixed time interval and uploads the same to the database.

`B_TimerTask`

```java
class B_TimerTask extends TimerTask {
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    @Override
    public void run() {


        // run on another thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                      //  Do the task of uploading to DB.

                    }
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    //Log the exception
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    //Log the message of e
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In the `onStartCommand()` of `T_Service`, I schedule the `B_TimerTask` as

```java
  private Timer mTimer = new Timer();
  mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new B_TimerTask(), 0, NOTIFY_INTERVAL);
```

Upon testing (several times), I find that the timer task stops executing after sometime (~26 minutes) and I see warnings on my `LogCat`

`E/Looper﹕ WARNING: The Looper class instance count has over a limit(100). There should be some leakage of Looper or HandlerThread.`

I'm unsure on how to rectify this issue and guessing that the leakage of the Handler might lead to the stopping of the TimerTask. Also, on closely checking the phone's memory usage (Allocated vs Free memory) on Android Studio, the rate of memory release is way slower than the memory that is allocated for the process. So I'm guessing that there might be a possibility of memory leak. 
I want to know how to avoid this kind of leakage or a better way to implement the function.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. Did you fix this?